# How can I prove that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom {2n} {n} x^n$

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-proofs

How can I prove that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom {2n} {n} x^n$?

I know the I should use Newton's generalized binomial theorem which says that,

$$(1+z)^a=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom {a} {n}z^n=1+\binom{a}{1}z+\binom{a}{2}z^2+...$$

But how can I use it in this special case?

Comment: Is your $z $ complex or real.

Comment: This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes the source of the problem, its motivation, your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.  Also, please don't assume in the post that the reader has looked at the title - once the question page is loaded, the reader is likely to skip over the title entirely.

Comment: Have you tried applying the generalized binomial series to obtain $$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4z}} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{-1/2}{n} (-4)^n z^n $$ and tried to simplify this? Also, please consider Carl Mummert's suggestion and improve your question by providing contexts.

Comment: Yes, I have reached $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4z}} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{-1/2}{n} (-4)^n z^n$$ but how can I continue it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray*}
\binom{-1/2}{n} (-4)^n = \frac{(-1/2)(-3/2) \cdots (-1/2-(n-1))}{n!} (-4)^n=\frac{(-1)^n(2n-1)!!}{2^n n!} \frac{(2n)!!}{2^n n!} (-4)^n = \binom{2n}{n}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use the catalan number generating function $C(z)=\sum_{n\ge 0}c_nz^{2n}$ to derive the generating function $f(z)$ for [NE lattice paths](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_path) from $(0,0)$ to $(n,n)$.

The catalan number generating function is:

$$C(z)=\frac{1}{2z^2}\left(1-\sqrt{1-4z^2}\right)\tag{1}$$

which gives, as it's $z^{2n}$ coefficient, the number of NE lattice paths starting at $(0,0)$, that  do not exceed the diagonal $y=x$, and terminate at $(n,n)$.

The *total* number of NE lattice paths starting at $(0,0)$ and that terminate at a diagonal coordinate $(n,n)$ is found by splitting NE lattice paths into $k=0,1,2,3,\ldots$ catalan paths joined by $2$ NE steps which intersect the diagonal (plus one step at the start and at the end). Since each catalan path may be either above or below the diagonal there is a multiplication factor of 2 for each catalan path generated by $C(z)$.

The generating function $f(z^2)=\sum_{n\ge 0}\binom{2n}{n}z^{2z}$ for *all paths* from $(0,0)$ to $(n,n)$ is therefore:

$$\begin{align}f(z^2)=(2C(z)z^2)^0+(2C(z)z^2)^1+&(2C(z)z^2)^2+(2C(z)z^2)^3+\cdots +(2C(z)z^2)^k+\cdots \\&=\frac{1}{1-2C(z)z^2}\tag{2}\end{align}$$

inputting $(1)$ into the right hand side of $(2)$ gives:

$$f(z^2)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4z^2}}$$
$$\implies f(z)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4z}}\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$